# How to declare array correctly

Tags: flutter, dart

I have problem with array. I want to send data to firebase but I can't because array is blocking me.

How can I declare an array of `Map`s?

example:

```
arr: ["1": {"v": 1, "b":0,},
      "2": {"v": 1, "b":0,},
      "3": {"v": 1, "b":0,},
]
```

not working:

```
var arr = [], var arr = [Map()];
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: @ChristopherMoore first declaration is good for simple array like ["s", "t", "v"] and second for [{}, {}, {},].

Comment: Could you clarify that? I'm still struggling to understand what you want and the issues with what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just forgetting braces around each of the `Map`s that you want to contain in your `List`.

```dart
var arr = [
  {"1": {"v": 1, "b":0,}},
  {"2": {"v": 1, "b":0,}},
  {"3": {"v": 1, "b":0,}},
]
```